# How to convert hour into seconds?

Tags: django, datetime, django-views

Here For example if the object has hour as `4hr` then I want to convert in seconds which should be `14400`.

```
HOURS = (
        ('1', '1 hrs'),
        ('2', '2 hrs'),
        ('4', '4 hrs'),
        ('6', '6 hrs'),
        ('12', '12 hrs'),
        ('24', '24 hrs'),
    )
   
    hour = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=HOURS)
```

views.py

```
obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
hour = obj.hour 
# now i Want to convert into seconds.
total_seconds = hour.total_seconds() ??
```

Comment: models.PositiveSmallIntegerField is the better choice for field type here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.hour` is a string, so you can not use `.total_seconds()` or anything similar. What you can do is use `int(…)` to convert the number to an `int`, and then multiply this with `3600` (since one hour is equal to 3'600 seconds):

```
total_seconds = int(hour) * 3600
```

It might however make more sense to use an [**`IntegerField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.IntegerField) here:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    HOURS = (
        (1, '1 hrs'),
        (2, '2 hrs'),
        (4, '4 hrs'),
        (6, '6 hrs'),
        (12, '12 hrs'),
        (24, '24 hrs'),
    )
   
    hour = models.IntegerField(choices=HOURS)
```

This will store the value numerically, and thus you do no longer need to call `int(…)`.